# Update Dynamic Data in RecyclerView With DiffUtil

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils

I'm Selecting Files From Device Which I Want To Upload On Firebase Storage. After Selecting Files I'm Showing The List Of Files in RecyclerView. I'm Using 3 List To Contain My Three Different Data FileName, Progress (To Show Progressbar of How Much Uploaded) And UploadStatus (To React ProgressBar According To The Status) But Now I Want To Change It To Only One List And Want to use DiffUtil To Update My Data.. But I Don't Know How To Implement it In My Case.

Here's My FileUpdate.java Model Class For DiffUtil.

```
public class FileUpdate {
private String name;
private int progress = 0;
private String status = "Loading";


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    FileUpdate that = (FileUpdate) o;
    return progress == that.progress && name.equals(that.name) && status.equals(that.status);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, progress, status);
}

public static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FileUpdate> itemCallback = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FileUpdate>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull FileUpdate oldItem, @NonNull FileUpdate newItem) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull FileUpdate oldItem, @NonNull FileUpdate newItem) {
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

Here's The Three List I'm Using. in UploadActivity.java

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            Intent intentReceived = result.getData();
            ClipData clipData = result.getData().getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < intentReceived.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri fileUri = intentReceived.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    String fileName = UploadActivity.this.getFileNameFromUri(fileUri);
                    uploadFile.add(fileName);
                    uploadStatus.add("Loading");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   
                    selectFiles.setEnabled(false);
                    
                    final int index = i;
                    
                    //Uploading File To Firebase Storage
                    StorageReference uploader = storageReference.child(Path).child(fileName);
                    uploader.putFile(fileUri)
                            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    try{
                                        progressValue.remove(index);
                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                    //Do Nothing
                                    }

                                    double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / snapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                                    Integer passProgress = Integer.valueOf(currentProgress);
                                    try{
                                        progressValue.add(index,passProgress);
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        progressValue.add(passProgress);
                                    }
                                    uploadStatus.remove(index);
                                    uploadStatus.add(index, "Processing");
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        uploadStatus.remove(index);
                        uploadStatus.add(index,"Done");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Successfully Uploaded " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     });
  }
}
```

This is Adapter Class I've Updated For DiffUtil.

```
public class AdminUploadFileAdapter extends ListAdapter<FileUpdate,AdminUploadFileAdapter.uploadViewHolder> {

protected AdminUploadFileAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FileUpdate> diffCallback) {
    super(diffCallback);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public uploadViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admin_upload_material_list_design,parent,false);
    return new uploadViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull uploadViewHolder holder, int position) {
    FileUpdate fileUpdate = getItem(position);
    holder.bind(fileUpdate);
}

public static class uploadViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView fileIcon,uploadComplete;
    ProgressBar uploadProgressBar;
    TextView uploadFileName;

    public uploadViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        uploadFileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_uploadFileName);
        fileIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_uploadFileIcon);
        uploadProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_fileUpload);
        uploadComplete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_uploadComplete);
        uploadProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    public void bind(FileUpdate fileUpdate){
        uploadFileName.setText(fileUpdate.getName());
        String fileStatus = fileUpdate.getStatus();
        if(fileStatus.equals("Processing")){
            uploadProgressBar.setProgress(fileUpdate.getProgress());
        }
        if(fileStatus.equals("Done")){
            uploadProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            uploadComplete.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_circle);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I Don't Know Which Changes I Need To Do To Add And Update My FileName, UploadStatus And Progressbar. I'm Beginner in This Thing.

Comment: Please read this post on capitalization, as sentence capitalization is in general considered more legible: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm Using 3 Lists Names uploadFile, uploadStatus And progressValue In The Code Of UploadActivity I've Shared. But I Want to Implement DiffUtil To Update The RecyclerView Not These Three Lists.. So What Changes I Need To Do To Implement DIffUtil List Successfully.. For That I've Also Made FileUpdate Model Class And Changed Some Necessary Things in Adapter But I Don't Know What Next I Should Do To Replace These Three Lists With DiffUtil List.